# Use of internal Node.js module vs. public npm-module

Tags: node.js

In order to keep the code clean I want to avoid using hard-coded values but use pre-defined constants such as HTTP status codes.

I can do it either with:

```js
import {constants as httpConstants} from "http2";

res.sendStatus(httpConstants.HTTP_STATUS_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
```

or with an npm-package such as [`http-status-codes`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-status-codes):

```js
import {StatusCodes} from 'http-status-codes';

res.sendStatus(StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
```

Do I understand it correctly that if `http2/constants` is a Node.js built-in module which is widely used internally by Node.js, the import of `http2/constants`, which is quite big, should not affect the app performance since it is already is in use by Node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the internal modules (including `http2`) are registered when Node starts. Quoting the [source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v16.4.1/src/node_binding.cc#L35):

```
// A list of built-in modules. In order to do module registration
// in node::Init(), need to add built-in modules in the following list.
// Then in binding::RegisterBuiltinModules(), it calls modules' registration
// function. This helps the built-in modules are loaded properly when
// node is built as static library. No need to depend on the
// __attribute__((constructor)) like mechanism in GCC.
#define NODE_BUILTIN_STANDARD_MODULES(V)
```

So yes, I'd rather use that module in your case.

---

By the way, technically HTTP status codes are not even part of http2 module: they're stored in [node_http_common.h](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v16.4.1/src/node_http_common.h#L125) file as set of macroses:

```
#define HTTP_STATUS_CODES(V)                                                  \
  V(CONTINUE, 100)                                                            \
  V(SWITCHING_PROTOCOLS, 101)                                                 \
  V(PROCESSING, 102)                                                          \
  V(EARLY_HINTS, 103)                                                         \
  V(OK, 200)                                                                  \
  // ...
```

... and, finally, are connected to [http2 module](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v16.4.1/src/node_http2.cc#L3232) `constants` prop in yet another series of #define statements:

```
#define V(name, _) NODE_DEFINE_CONSTANT(constants, HTTP_STATUS_##name);
  HTTP_STATUS_CODES(V)
#undef V
```

What's funny though is that there's another place in Node storing the same data reversed (status codes are keys, not values): it's [http module](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_status_codes). [Source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v16.4.1/lib/_http_server.js#L100):

```
const STATUS_CODES = {
  100: 'Continue',                   // RFC 7231 6.2.1
  101: 'Switching Protocols',        // RFC 7231 6.2.2
  102: 'Processing',                 // RFC 2518 10.1 (obsoleted by RFC 4918)
  103: 'Early Hints',                // RFC 8297 2
  200: 'OK',                         // RFC 7231 6.3.1
  201: 'Created',                    // RFC 7231 6.3.2
  // ...
```

Comment: Regarding «there's another place in Node storing», yes I've also paid attention but since I want to use this module as an enums, `http2/constants` seems to be more appropriate option.

Comment: Do you know, perhaps, if there is somewhere in Node.js hard-coded constant for `https` and for `x-forwarded-proto` values to avoid hardcoding it?

Comment: No, I'm not aware of such things. Even if there's some, node itself [doesn't use it](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/0738a2b7bd011c421b458e586c49f9a7f2657b90/lib/_http_incoming.js#L321).